# Blend mode not available

Tags: transparency

I am trying to create a transparent material, but it still doesn't appear so. I think it's because the blend mode is set to opaque, but I can't change it. In the material settings I can only see surface displacement and volume. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your material settings?

Comment: You are in Cycles render, switch back to EEVEE.